# проблема с добавлением данных в базу данных

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, crud

есть функция в контроллере

```
function action_add() {

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];

        if(empty($title)) {
    $error = 'Please enter the title';
        }
        if(empty($description)) {
            $error = 'Please enter the desc';
        }

        if(!isset($error)){
            $data = array(
                'title' => $title,
                'description' => $description
            );
    $this->model->add_data($data);
        }


    }
    $this->view->generate('main/add_view.php','template_view.php');
}
```

вот так представлена форма во вьюхе

```
<form class="main_form" method="post"">
    <label class="form-group">
        <span class="color_element">*</span> Заголовок:
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Ваш заголовок" data-validation-required-message="Вы не ввели заголовок" required />
    </label>
    <label class="form-group">
        <span class="color_element">*</span> Текст Вашей новости:
        <textarea name="description" placeholder="text text text" data-validation-required-message="Вы не ввели основную часть новости" required></textarea>
    </label>
    <input type='submit' name="submit" value='Добавить' class="button">
</form>
```

и модель

```
public function add_data($data) {

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news VALUES ('".$data['title']."', '".$data['description'].")"); 
}
```

ошибок и нотайсов нет, но данные не заносятся 
укажите, пожалуйста на ошибки и недочеты, заранее спасибо

Comment: Почему у формы не указан action? И еще лишняя кавычка в конце. Данные из формы точно уходят на требуемую Вам страницу? Какой фреймворк используется? Вы проверяли, что метод action_add вообще вызывается при отправке формы?

Comment: ибо совсем забыл про него.. а как, тогда, в action указать метод action_add? нет, не доходят, свой мини фреймфорк, так сказать делаю сейчас велосипед, да он вызывается при отправке

Comment: В запросе у Вас не хватает одной закрывающей одинарной кавычки после $data['description']. У Вас вывод ошибок отключен?

Answer (score 1):

Надо action добавить

```
 <form class="main_form" method="post"" action ="">
```

Comment: да это косяк, но проблема видимо не только в этом.. даже после добавления ничего не изменилось